# Screen sheetname in formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macros in VBA that first creates new sheet with "_frozen" suffix to active one and then inserts formulas that depends on that sheet to cells. The problem appears when active sheet contains parentheses or spaces in name, like "Sheet3 (2)" - it occurs when it is a copy of existing one. Than the frozen sheet will be "Sheet3 (2)_frozen" and formulas look like

```
=(Sheet3 (2)_frozen!B6 / Sheet3 (2)_frozen!D6) > 0
```

Of course, it does not work. So my question is how can I screen sheetname in formulas to avoid this? Simply added quotes around sheetname do not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula should be:

```
=('Sheet3 (2)_frozen'!B6 / 'Sheet3 (2)_frozen'!D6) > 0
```